# Error while installing setuptools in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

When I try to install setuptools in python 3. I get the following error.

python3-setuptools : Depends: python3 (>= 3.1.2-8~) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 0.6.24-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have python 3.6 installed. Still its giving the error.
 How to rectify the broken packages?

Comment: It sounds you have held the packages from being installed, check `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`.

Comment: @NilsWerner dpkg --get-selections | grep hold is not giving any output.

Comment: Can you show us how exactly you are trying to install setuptools?